# Find all ideals of $K \times K$ where K is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that there is no nontrivial ideals of any field $K$. Again  $K \times 0$ and $0 \times K$ are nontrivial ideals of $K \times K$. But how can we give a complete classification for all ideals of $K \times K$? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If an ideal contains the element $(a,b)$ where $a \ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$, what else must it contain?

Answer (score 2):

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are rings, every ideal $I$ in $A_1 \times A_2$ can be written as $I_1 \times I_2$; now a field $\mathbb{K}$ has only two ideals, $(0)$ and $\mathbb{K}$. Endstory.

Comment: Reducing to a harder problem?

Comment: @Myself it's not really harder, if you look at my answer you'll see this is quite easy to prove since we have the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @Adam Hughes: If it's a "research problem" I agree with you, but this is more likely from a chapter one in ring theory. So no Endstory (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The image of an ideal under the canonical projection homomorphisms onto each factor would also be an ideal by definition of a homomorphism and by the first isomorphism theorem, **all** ideals arise in this way, so looking at

$$\pi_1:\begin{cases}K\times K\to K \\ (a,b)\mapsto a\end{cases}$$
$$\pi_2:\begin{cases}K\times K\to K \\ (a,b)\mapsto b\end{cases}$$

and noting that the only ideals of $K$ are $\{0\}$ and $K$, you get the ideals to be

$$\{\pi_1^{-1}(I)\times\pi_2^{-1}(J)\}=\{\{0\}\times\{0\}, \{0\}\times K, K\times\{0\}, K\times K\}$$

where here, $I,J\in\{\{0\},K\}$.

Comment: Could you please expand the section where you explain how these are the only ideals?

Comment: @Myself that the only ideals of a field, $K$, are $\{0\}$ and $K$ is a more basic problem the op says he already understands in his original post. If you're interested in why this is, it's considered appropriate to post a question of your own and link this one to indicate why you're interested.

Comment: sorry that was not really what I meant. I mean the point where you apply the first isomorphism theorem to conclude that every ideal arises from on of the two morphisms that you give. I mean, *a priori* there may be other morphisms that you haven't considered so this point is a bit unclear.

Comment: So to be completely clear, the first isomorphism theorem states that every ideal *containing the kernel of the morphism* can be retraced in the image of the morphism, in other words you have found every morphism containing the kernel of either of both your morphisms, that leaves open the question if a morphism must necessarily contain one of those kernels.

Comment: @Myself Any surjective homomorphism will do, all maps out of $K\times K$ arise as a product of two maps, this is the **definition** of a direct product. It would take another line, but using this one can show that any other just reduces to this case. I opted for being succinct rather than pedantic for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. Why does your proof not apply to show that the only subgroups of $\mathbf C_p \times \mathbf C_p$ are $1$, $1\times\mathbf C_p$, $\mathbf C_p\times 1$ and $\mathbf C_p \times\mathbf C_p$.

Comment: These are ring maps, not group maps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16904/discussion-between-myself-and-adam-hughes).